# UITableView header height changes, but the tableview does not move

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, height

In my project, the UITableView header shrinks by about 35 pixels due to the hiding of a UI element.

I can change the UITableView header and all related constraints; but the table view itself never seems to move and stays at the offset of 35 pixels leaving a gap.

Is there something I need to be doing to ensure that the UITableView is always snagging or hugging the bottom of the UITableView header; regardless of what size it might be?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I had to recalculate the new height and set the height of the table view header.

```
 CGRect newFrame = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
        newFrame.size.height = newFrame.size.height - (height-10);

        self.tableHeaderView.frame = newFrame;
        [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.tableHeaderView];
```